# Why cannot we access a table created in master db whose name does not start with "sp_" from a user db?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

I read somewhere that if we create a table in master db by using `sp_sometablename` it will be accessible from any other user database.

e.g.

```
use master
create table sp_TestTbl(Id int identity, Name varchar(20))
//Table created
```

Now if I execute the below

```
use test
select * from sp_TestTbl
```

it worked.

Whereas, if I don't prefix the table name with `sp_`, though the table will be created in master db, but we cannot access it from any of the user database

```
use master
create table abc_TestTbl(Id int identity, Name varchar(20))

use test
select * from abc_TestTbl
```

**Error:**

> Msg 208, Level 16, State 1, Line 6 Invalid object name
>   'abc_TestTbl'.

what is the cause?

Thanks

Comment: I would **NEVER** use an `sp_` prefix on a **table** - it is often used in stored procedures, but it's a prefix that's been reserved by Microsoft for its use - **don't use it!** If you have a table `abc_TestTbl` in `master` (also: you **shouldn't** create stuff in `master` anyway!), then you can select from it using `select * from master.dbo.abc_TestTbl` - no matter **what prefix** it has ....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
use master
create table abc_TestTbl(Id int identity, Name varchar(20))

use test
select * from master.dbo.abc_TestTbl
```

You need to fully qualify the table name when using from another DB

**BUT**

This is a ***completely bad idea*** - to create user objects in master database.

The **sp_** prefix is handled differently by Sql Server - it looks for the object in master DB first for this prefix

Comment: Correct.. i never do this but for experimental sake i have asked..but why for sp_ case we don't have to give a fully qualified name but have to give for the other case?

Comment: Appended answer for sp_ prefix